# Vuetify 3 v-date-picker giving empty array on selecting date and clicking Ok

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am creating a Registration app in Vue-3.3.4 and using Vuetify-3.3.10. In there I have a text field called "Date of Birth" to which I have appended a calendar icon. When I click the icon, it will open a Dialog box (using v-dialog) and it will contain the date picker to select date (v-date-picker). When I select the date and click Ok in the calendar, it binds an empty array to the variable used in v-model. Also, on clicking the date-picker is not highlighting the selected date either.

Full Source code: [GitHub](https://github.com/wambling/vue-date-picker-issue)

App.vue

```
<template>
      <v-container>
        <v-card width="500px" height="200px">
          <v-card-title>Date Picker Test</v-card-title>
          <v-card-item>
            <v-row class="mt-2">
              <v-col >
                <v-card-text>
                  <v-text-field
                      v-model="dateOfBirth"
                      type="text"
                      label="*Date of Birth"
                      append-inner-icon="mdi-calendar"
                      :clearable="true"
                      density="compact"
                      variant="outlined"
                      @click:append-inner="showCalendar(true)">
                  </v-text-field>
                </v-card-text>
              </v-col>
            </v-row>
          </v-card-item>
        </v-card>

        <base-dialog
            :is-visible="showDialog"
            @close-calendar="showCalendar(false)"
            @save-value = "dob"
        ></base-dialog>
      </v-container>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';
import BaseDialog from './components/ui/BaseDialog.vue';
export default defineComponent({
  components: {
    'base-dialog': BaseDialog,
  },
  setup() {
    const showDialog = ref<boolean>(false);
    const dateOfBirth = ref<any>(undefined);
    const showCalendar = (show:boolean) => {
      showDialog.value = show;
    }

    const dob = (val:any) =>{
      console.log("Date of Birth =>", val);
    }

    return {
      showDialog,
      dateOfBirth, showCalendar, dob
    }
  }

})
</script>
```

BaseDialog.vue

```
<template>
    <teleport to="body">
        <v-dialog :model-value="isVisible" width="auto">
          <v-date-picker
              v-model="date"
              style="{font-size: 20px}"
              title="Date of Birth"
              calendarIcon="mdi-calendar-account"
              collapseIcon="mdi-calendar-collapse-horizontal"
              expandIcon="mdi-calendar-expand-horizontal"
              keyboardIcon="mdi-keyboard"
              showAdjacentMonths
              elevation="20"
              color="primary"
              @click:cancel="closeCalendar"
              @click:save="saveValue"
              :min="1900"
              :max="2024"
          ></v-date-picker>
        </v-dialog>
    </teleport>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { defineComponent, ref, watch } from 'vue';
import { VDatePicker } from 'vuetify/labs/components';
export default defineComponent({
    components: {
        'v-date-picker': VDatePicker
    },
  emits:['close-calendar', 'save-value'],
    props: {
        isVisible: {
            type: Boolean,
            required: true
        }
    },
    setup(props, context) {
      const date = ref<any>(undefined);

      watch(date, (newValue)=> {
        console.log('Base Dialog Watch => ', newValue);
      })
      const closeCalendar = ()=> {
        context.emit('close-calendar');
      };
      const saveValue = () => {
        context.emit('save-value', date.value);
        closeCalendar();
      }
      return {
        date, closeCalendar, saveValue
      }
    }
})
</script>
```

[image: Text Field]

[image: Date Picker]

Console output:

[image: Console Output]

I am new to Vuetify and I know v-date-picker is added in Vuetify version 3.3.4, but even in their official document code example I did observe that when I clicked a date it is not highlighting there either.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are simply not assigning the value returned from your date component to `dateOfBirth`. Just add it to your handler:

```
      const dob = (val:any) =>{
        console.log("Date of Birth =>", val);
        dateOfBirth.value = val // <----- assign it back
      }
```

Here it is in a [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

---

As a tip, it is good practice in Vue to bring data binding back to [`v-model`](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/v-model.html) syntax, as it gives a clearer structure while needing less code, which makes it easier to read and comprehend:

```html
    <base-dialog
      v-model:isVisible="showDialog"
      v-model:dateOfBirth="dateOfBirth"
    ></base-dialog>
```

For this to work you need to update the events emitted from your base dialog:

```
  export default defineComponent({
      emits:['update:isVisible', 'update:dateOfBirth'], // <---- update events
      props: {
          isVisible: {
              type: Boolean,
              required: true
          },
          dateOfBirth: { // <---- add input prop
              type: Date,
          }
      },
      setup(props, context) {
        const date = ref<any>(undefined);

        watchEffect(() => date.value = props.dateOfBirth ?? '') // <--- internal value should match value from outside

        const closeCalendar = ()=> {
          context.emit('update:isVisible', false);
        };
        const saveValue = () => {
          context.emit('update:dateOfBirth', date.value);
          closeCalendar();
        }
        return {
          date, closeCalendar, saveValue
        }
      }
  })
```

Here is another [playground](https://play.vuetifyjs.com/#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)

Comment: thanks for quick reply. I see in your code that the date we select is not getting highlighted which was my second issue here.

Comment: What do you mean with "highlighted"? The selected date gets a big purple (primary) dot in my browser: https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9tyN.png

Comment: This is strange. I am using Mac OS Ventura and tried on Opera and Chrome (latest version) and both places when I click on a date, it doesn't get a big purple and no error in the console either.

Comment: Hmm, weird. Does it happen with the playgound linked in the answer too?

Comment: Yes it is happening with playground link as well. Even in the official documentation site, when I click the date picker... date doesn't get highlighted.

Comment: The first example on the documentation page does not seem to select at all, but the other ones work for me with Firefox and Chromium on Xubuntu. Internally, VDatePicker uses VBtn with primary color as default. When you put `bg-primary` class on a random element, do you get a background color?